# How to stop AEM from including author instance javascripts on the publisher instance

Tags: aem

The publisher instance has the following javascript files included:

- /etc/clientlibs/granite/jquery.min.js
- /etc/clientlibs/granite/utils.min.js
- /etc/clientlibs/granite/jquery/granite.min.js
- /etc/clientlibs/foundation/main.min.js
- /etc/clientlibs/granite/jquery/granite/csrf.min.js

It would be best to exclude them for performance and also the fact that I am using jQuery 2.0 as my part of AEM site.

Comment: Those aren't necessarily author instance specific scripts.

Comment: Ok if not maybe at least remove /etc/clientlibs/granite/jquery.min.js . I am not using it part of my project.

Answer (score 2):

These scripts(not including the `csrf.min.js`) are part of the category `cq.foundation-main`. You can use this utility for checking this.
http://localhost:4502/libs/granite/ui/content/dumplibs.test.html?categories=cq.foundation-main

If you create your page template components by extending the OOTB `wcm/foundation/components/page` (assuming you use sightly), AEM will add these scripts in the head section. More specifically these are included in `headlibs.html` file present under the OOTB page component.

To overcome this, you can override this file in your component, and either comment this below line or include it conditionally only when wcmmode is edit.
`<sly data-sly-test="${wcmmode.edit}" data-sly-call="${clientLib.all @ categories='cq.foundation-main'}" />`

For JSP based components (`foundation/components/page`), the same thing is done in `headlibs.jsp`.

By the way, you wouldn't want to remove the CSRF JS. It's AEM's solution to counter CSRF issues.

Answer (score 0):

What you see is the clientcontext related js'es

The script that loads the given js'es is as below (or sth similiar)

`<cq:include path="clientcontext" resourceType="cq/personalization/components/clientcontext"/>`

either you exclude it completely for publish (wcmMode=disabled) which would probably break sth related to analytics on your publish, or change the include to some overwrite of the clientcontext component that you'd develop.

If you however don't use any native Adobe integration you should be safe just with excluding the thing.